# How to work with libtool?

Tags: software-installation, development

I try to install [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/installation/unix.html#installation) and have a problem with last command in tutorial:

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/mapserv /usr/local/bin/mapserv
```

Terminal says that cannot find command `libtool`/ I went and installed [libtool](http://petio.org/tools/libtool.html). But still command not work. I try:

```
libtool install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/mapserv /usr/local/bin/mapserv
```

And get an error:

```
libtool: you must specify a MODE
```

What am I doing wrong?

OS:Mint. 
PS: First time see a Linux system.

Comment: fwiw, in the initial output, the command being executed is coming from libtool in some way but the actual command being executed is `/usr/bin/install -c .libs/mapserv /usr/local/bin/mapserv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you as a normal user of the system do not work directly with `libtool` at all. [Libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) is a convenience utility for software developers. You can see its effects, but if you ever have to "work with `libtool`" to get some software to build, it means something is broken. And then, you don't so much work with `libtool` to fix it as attempt to fix the package's build system. This may include replacing the copy of `libtool` you got with that package.

That's the key thing you have to understand about Libtool: when you install it on your system, as you have done, you don't get a `libtool` program to run. The main command you get is `libtoolize`, and its primary purpose is to generate the `libtool` script shipped with a source tarball.

So, this software you're trying to build isn't using the `libtool` command on the system, it's using the one that came with the source tarball. About all you as a normal user can hope to try is replacing it by re-running `libtoolize`, but I wouldn't recommend that as a general troubleshooting step. It has a pretty decent chance of breaking things rather than fixing them.

Answer (score 2):

In this documentation, the "libtool" line is output you're supposed to read, not a command you're supposed to type in. The command you're supposed to enter is the "make install" command, and the "libtool:" line is part of the output of that command.